# PHP Regex Replace before and after unknown string

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

This is driving me absolutely crazy.

If I have a string such as this, where the value after 'udp://' varies:

```
LONDON Remote server cluster 88: taken
udp://8379f690ba57e0fdf8f944324a4453de67780

BRUSSELS: Hosted MPLS cluster
udp://5b0e9bc72b989c87a9a70da7865dbb5b4aa9c086

PARIS: Hosted atrium access
udp://39415215319c9brt6b9c7d10238c19cc82e7f88b

PRAGUE: Main Office acces
udp://e721f751ab0936706192cf15b4632889b38f131a
```

How can I use regex in PHP to make it look like so:

```
LONDON Remote server cluster 88: taken
http://www.8379f690ba57e0fdf8f944324a4453de67780/tsa.a3m

BRUSSELS: Hosted MPLS cluster
http://www.5b0e9bc72b989c87a9a70da7865dbb5b4aa9c086/tsa.a3m

PARIS: Hosted atrium access
http://www.39415215319c9brt6b9c7d10238c19cc82e7f88b/tsa.a3m

PRAGUE: Main Office acces
http://www.e721f751ab0936706192cf15b4632889b38f131a/tsa.a3m
```

So far I've managed this to get this regex:

```
(?<=udp:\/\/)(.*)(?=)
```

which finds the long alphanumeric value after 'udp://' but how do I use this to do a replace with the new values of 'http://' before the value and '/tsa.a3m' after it?  Bare in mind the strings on the lines inbetween these values vary at all time as well.  I read I have to use preg_replace but can't figure out how to get that to find the precious alphanumeric value, hang on to it and discard the 'udp://' replace it with 'http://' and append '/tsa.a3m'

I tried something like this but it doesn't work and it doesn't give any specific errors:

```
$value = '/(?<=udp:\/\/)(.*)(?=)/';
$string[]='http://www';
$string[]= $value;
$string[]='/tsa.a3m';
$string = join('',$string);
$replace = 'udp://'.$variable;
$data = preg_replace("/($replace, $string, ($_POST['text']));
```

I will be so grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a lookbehind, because that doesn't get included in the match, so it doesn't get replaced.

```
$data = preg_replace('#udp://(\S*)#', 'http://www.$1/tsa.a3m', $_POST['text']);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/O10pBH)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked except that the /tsa.a3m is being added to a new line ?

Comment: I don't know why that would happen. Is it possible you have HTML markup like `<br>` after the URL? I've added a demo showing that it works properly with a normal string.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for the demo, I think the problem is related to how the php is processnig the input text from the HTML form.  I've written a detailed question about it here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915684/html-form-post-data-using-php-for-regex-replace-causes-weird-eol-entries-m]

Comment: I think whats happening is that because of the way PHP is reading info from my textbox its including linebreaks.  Do you know of a  way I can express '#udp://(.*)#' but telling it to ignore any line breaks that appear immediately after - its as if the (.*) is sucking up the line break character as well (which I think is ^m) so when the /tsa.a3m is added to the end of the variable string it appears on the next line.

Comment: I've changed the regexp to use `\S*` instead of `.*`, so it stops replacing at any whitespace, which includes any kind of newline.